# code to turn on transition setting on phone within app

Tags: java, android, adt, transition

I have this app where when it navigates to another activity it does a transition animation. Now I have already got that working properly but, to get it to work i have to turn the animation setting on my phone on. I have been searching on Google and I can"t seem to find solution to my problem. So my problem is this,is it possible to turn this setting on from within the app, with a code, instead of having to manually do it?
Here is the code but as i have said above this works perfectly and I'm using a Telstra next G Huawei phone, just want to no if i can code it so i can turn the animation setting on if i decide to put it on a different phone.
//Button to restart from beginning:

```
    //Declaring the button for OnClickListener and EditText to send data:
            private void Restart() {
                Button Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restart3);
                Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    //The action the button takes when clicked:
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //Goes back to the start of app:
                        Intent i = new Intent(Height.this, Page_1.class);
                        //clears the stack of all Activities that were open before this one so that they don't stack up:
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        //The transition animation when going onto next page:
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
                        // to end the current activity:
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Which phone you are using?? Paste your code here